# User with read access to publishing images is unable to view an image link

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a SharePoint Online publishing site with a home page that contains an image from the "Images" document library.  The "Visitors" group on the site has "Read" access to this document library.  I've added "Everyone but external users" to the "Visitors" group.  When one of the users goes to the home page they are unable to see the image and if they try to go to the image directly through the address bar they get an "Access Denied" message.  However, if I give the "Visitors" group "Contribute" access to the "Images" document library then they are able to see the image on the home page.

It makes no sense to me, but why would I need to give them "Contribute" access just to be able to see the image?  Why wouldn't "Read" access be enough?

Comment: Check versioning settings. Ensure that its set to `Create major versions` and Require content approval is set to `No`

Comment: @GautamSheth `Require content approval` was set to `No` but the other was set to `Create major and minor versions`.  I'm assuming then that it was only a draft (minor version) that I was creating and so the other users could not see it because it wasn't published.  It would be nice if SharePoint was smart enough to prevent me from publishing a page that links to unpublished content.

Comment: That's correct. The draft versions are not visible to visitors. You need to publish those items.

Comment: @GautamSheth Can you please turn your comment into an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the images are not visible is because in your `Images` library, require Major and Minor version settings is turned on.

Because of that, whenever you first upload an image, it remains in draft state, visible only to admins, approvers and the uploader. It wont be available for users with read rights. To make it visible to all, you need to check in and publish the image.

To fix this issue, you can change the setting to `Create major versions` only. This will by default do away with need to check-in & publish each and every item uploaded and make it visible to users with read rights.

You dont need to modify the library permission settings or break inheritance for this.